# How we can align one or more textviews one below to another in table row of table layout in android through java code not xml

Tags: android

I am consrtucting a registration form in table layout for which I have to add various textviews in a table row one one below another.

Comment: Do you want `TextView`s to be in different rows (which will stack them automatically) or stack them one-below-other in the same row.

Comment: just stack them one below another in the same row.

Comment: Have you considered putting them in a `LinearLayout`, then then putting the linear layout inside the `TableRow`? I can post the code if you want?

Comment: plz post the code anyway I have tried but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get something like this:

[image]

Here is the code, you can get the basic idea.

```
      // <table>
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(context);

        // <row1>
        TableRow row = new TableRow(context);

        // <column1>
        LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(context);
        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        container.addView(getSampleTextView("Stacked TextView 1", "#ff0000"));
        container.addView(getSampleTextView("Stacked TextView 2", "#ffff00"));

        row.addView(container);
        // </column1>

        // <column2>
        row.addView(getSampleTextView("TextView in Another Column", "#ffffff"));
        // </column2>

        table.addView(row);
        // </row1>

        // <row2>
        TableRow row2 = new TableRow(context);
        row2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffff"));
        row2.addView(getSampleTextView("TextView in Next Row", "#0000ff"));
        table.addView(row2);
        // </row2>
```

Here is how I get sample text view for demo purposes:

```
 private TextView getSampleTextView(String text, String color) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        return textView;
    }
```